# background issue on phone(s5)

Tags: css

I just create page [pmwebdev.co.uk](http://pmwebdev.co.uk)
And everything is fine on deskop, but when i used my phone to check, my background start jumping like crazy... even when i resize my web in deskop windows everything was fine... need help.

css code

```
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

body{
    background-image: url("bg.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    [class*="col-"] {
        width: 100%;
    }
    img

    {margin-top: 20px;
        margin:auto;
        height: 100px;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    #welcome{
        font-size: 30px;

    }
    #date{
        font-size: 30px;
        stroke-dasharray: 10 2;
    }
    svg{
        height: 200px;
    }
circle{
    stroke-width:10px;
}


}
```

Comment: fixed background is not supported in mobile browsers, due to performance limitations. See: http://quirksmode.org/css/backgrounds-borders/mobile.html#t00

Comment: O thanks. I think I know how I going to fix it 